# Date missing exception

Tags: laravel

I am stuck. I´ve got an exception Data Missing

```
if ($date instanceof DateTimeInterface) {
        $instance = static::instance($date);
        $instance::setLastErrors($lastErrors);

        return $instance;
    }

    if (static::isStrictModeEnabled()) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(implode(PHP_EOL, $lastErrors['errors']));
    }

    return false;
}
```

I had a module called Date_Exams where the admin can select an exam and use a date picker to enter a date. The date picker uses Jquery and I do not have any problem to store the date in Mysql format.

The problem appears when I go to the screen Exam Registration and use a dynamic select appears the date available of this exam in format d-m-Y but when I try to store this value show me the exception.

I think It is something related to Carbon formatting, but I am not really sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably connected with the formats, Carbon expects another format than `d-m-Y`.

You can change the date format within the model with the protected attribute `$dateFormat`.

But i would store and handle all dates in ISO 8601-format and just display the dates in whatever format is suitable in the views.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any code suggestions? It is something like protected $dateFormat = ['booking_date];